# User permission to join client to domain

Tags: permissions, windows-sbs-2008

The prebuilt network admin is at the moment the only account that is allowed to join clients to the domain, other members of the Domain Admin group are not allowed to.

Is there a certain group they have to join, or some GPO to tweak, in order to get that permission?

Answer (score 0):

Got it [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/1a7b3cc3-a4d6-4958-99af-3ccdc5d94e28/users-to-add-computers-to-domain-firewall-thro-gpo).

1. Open the Default Domain Group policy.
2. Navigate through Computer Configuration / Windows Settings / Security Settings / Local Policies / User Rights Assignment.
3. Expand User Rights Assignment.
4. Double-click Add workstations to Domain.
5. Check the Define these policy settings box.
6. Press the Add User or Group button.
7. Complete the dialog to add the user or group.
8. Press Apply and OK.